# C#, cannot set DownloadFile() timeout

Tags: c#, download, timeout

I need to download some large files, so I need a longer DownloadFile() timeout than the default 1 minute.

Problem is that my solution doesn't increase the timeout. It stays at 1 minute.

I have created this class:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    private int timeout;
    
    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            timeout = value;
        }
    }

    public MyWebClient()
    {
        this.timeout = 1200000;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = this.timeout;
        return w;
    }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
{
    client.Timeout = 1200000;
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileUrl), localFile);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below

```
private class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = Timeout;
        ((HttpWebRequest) w).ReadWriteTimeout = Timeout;
        return w;
    }
}
```

and call as you have mentioned.

UPDATED:--
other wise use as below

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.Timeout = 1200000;
req.ReadWriteTimeout = 1200000;
var w = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(localFile))
{
    w.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in client request

```
using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
{
  client.Timeout = 1200000;
  byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
  File.WriteAllBytes(localFile, data);    
}
```